# xpath in lxml for python get just a single node

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have this xml document. I am trying to put the group of data shown here as 1-7 into the Data category. When using Xpath, I can generally filter to where I need to be, but it seems when I access Con1, instead of giving me only that set of children for that, it gives me everything in the same level of "dict"

```
<dict>
<key>Tester</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Con1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeySet</key>
            <dict>
                <key>B52:B53:B54</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0:0:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>1</string>
                                <string>2</string>
                                <string>3</string>
                                <string>4</string>
                                <string>5</string>
                                <string>6</string>
                                <string>7</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>15:15:3</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>7:15:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>7:15:1</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>Con2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeySet</key>
            <dict>
                <key>B52:B53:B54</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0:0:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0:16:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0:48:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>Con3</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeySet</key>
            <dict>
                <key>B52:B53:B54</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0:0:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

So if i write:

```
myPath = '//dict[key/text()="Tester"]/dict[key/text()="Con1"][1]'
x = tree.xpath(myPath)
etree.tostring(x, pretty_print=True)
```

I will get:

```
     <dict>
        <key>Con1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeySet</key>
            <dict>
                <key>B52:B53:B54</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0:0:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>1</string>
                                <string>2</string>
                                <string>3</string>
                                <string>4</string>
                                <string>5</string>
                                <string>6</string>
                                <string>7</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>15:15:3</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>7:15:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>7:15:1</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>Con2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeySet</key>
            <dict>
                <key>B52:B53:B54</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0:0:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0:16:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0:48:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>Con3</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeySet</key>
            <dict>
                <key>B52:B53:B54</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0:0:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

I am hoping to only get that first Connection set so i can add my data correctly to it. So my ideal output when running that set of code would look like:

```
     <dict>
        <key>Con1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>KeySet</key>
            <dict>
                <key>B52:B53:B54</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>0:0:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>1</string>
                                <string>2</string>
                                <string>3</string>
                                <string>4</string>
                                <string>5</string>
                                <string>6</string>
                                <string>7</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>15:15:3</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>7:15:0</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>7:15:1</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Data</key>
                            <array/>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

For Andersson's response I will edit the source by using this code. It does work, but having problems identifying the correct level it should be placed at due to the issue above.

```
for parent in tree.xpath(myPath)
    parent.insert(1, data)
```

Comment: You cannot modify source with XPath, e.g. remove `<key>Con2</key>`, `<key>Con3</key>` from `dict` node

Comment: @Andersson I cannot edit the base of my xml file. I can edit the source though by using   for parent in tree.xpath(mypath): parent.insert(1, data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debug i found that if i add the "/dict" call in I can separate my sections and access them using [#]

So instead of this:

```
myPath = '//dict[key/text()="Tester"]/dict[key/text()="Con1"][1]'
```

Using this

```
myPath = '//dict[key/text()="Tester"]/dict[key/text()="Con1"]/dict[1]'
```